# How can I avoid seemingly unneccessary wrappers like this?

Tags: c#

I have a manager class (included below) and sub data types that are included inside it. All of the different stored types are more or less the same with some wrapper functions calling the exact same named function below to the sub object. This feels dirty and I can't help but think there's a better way to do this. Suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Inspire.Shared.Models.Enums;
using Lidgren.Network;

namespace GameServer.Editor.ContentLocking
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The content lock manager helps provide delegation
    /// </summary>
    public class ContentLockManager
    {

        // This is a mapping of all the different content lock stores available
        Dictionary<ContentType, ContentLockStore> _contentLockStores = new Dictionary<ContentType, ContentLockStore>();

        public ContentLockManager()
        {
            // Generate the ContentMap dynamically, assinging everyone a backing
            foreach (var contentType in GetValues<ContentType>())
                _contentLockStores.Add(contentType, new ContentLockStore());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invalidates and purges all locks for a given connection.
        /// This is typically called when a connection has disconnected from the node.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connection"></param>
        public void PurgeLocks(NetConnection connection)
        {
            foreach (var contentLockStore in _contentLockStores.Values)
            {
                contentLockStore.ReleaseLocks(connection);
            }
        }

        public List<int> GetLockedContent(ContentType contentType)
        {
            var contentStore = _contentLockStores[contentType];
            return contentStore.GetLockedContentIDs();
        }

        public bool HasLock(NetConnection connection, int ID, ContentType contentType)
        {
            var contentStore = _contentLockStores[contentType];
            return contentStore.HasLock(connection, ID);
        }

        public bool AnyoneHasLock(NetConnection connection, int ID, ContentType contentType)
        {
            var contentStore = _contentLockStores[contentType];
            return contentStore.AnyoneHasLock(connection, ID);
        }

        public bool TryAcquireLock(NetConnection connection, int ID, ContentType contentType)
        {
            var contentStore = _contentLockStores[contentType];
            return contentStore.TryAcquireLock(connection, ID);
        }

        public bool TryReleaseLock(NetConnection connection, int ID, ContentType contentType)
        {
            var contentStore = _contentLockStores[contentType];
            return contentStore.ReleaseLock(connection, ID);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>()
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
        }

    }
}
```

And then I have a mapping inside like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Lidgren.Network;

namespace GameServer.Editor.ContentLocking
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A collection of keys internally of content that has been locked
    /// </summary>
    public class ContentLockStore
    {
        // Current locks on a particular piece of content
        private Dictionary<int, NetConnection> _contentLocks = new Dictionary<int, NetConnection>(); 

        public bool TryAcquireLock(NetConnection connection, int ID)
        {
            // Trying to aqquire a lock for something you already have or you're not authorized to obtain
            if (_contentLocks.ContainsKey(ID))
                return false;

            // Noone has taken it - go ahead and grab this
            _contentLocks.Add(ID, connection);

            return true;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Release sall locks with an associated contention
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connection"></param>
        public void ReleaseLocks(NetConnection connection)
        {
            var keys = _contentLocks.Where(cLock => cLock.Value == connection).ToList();
            keys.ForEach(x => ReleaseLock(x.Value, x.Key));

        }

        public bool ReleaseLock(NetConnection connection, int ID)
        {
            // If they don't have a lock, they can't release it
            if (!HasLock(connection, ID))
                return false;

            // Release the lock
            _contentLocks.Remove(ID);

            return true;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of all the locked content IDs for a particular store
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<int> GetLockedContentIDs()
        {
            return _contentLocks.Keys.ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether a particular connection has a lock on a piece of content
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connection"></param>
        /// <param name="ID"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool HasLock(NetConnection connection, int ID)
        {
            // If the key dosen't even exist, don't bother
            if (!_contentLocks.ContainsKey(ID))
                return false;

            return _contentLocks[ID] == connection;

        }

        public bool AnyoneHasLock(NetConnection connection, int ID)
        {
            return _contentLocks.ContainsKey(ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the relationship between the two classes.  What does the constructor for `ContentLockManager` do? Are IDs always `int`?  What other mappings do you have other than `ContentLockStore`?

Comment: @Bobson The lock manager is creating a backing store for every ContentType and adding it to the dictionary. IDs are always ints - as defined. It's just a pure backing store. I need a ContentType locking store each ContentType. Basically, when a piece of content is opened I want it "locked" to that connection. This is done per content piece (by ID) and per content type.

Comment: So, `Manager` -> list of all things that can be locked, and `Store` -> individual item's locks?  And you have multiple `Store` classes, for each type of `item`?

Comment: @Bobson That is correct.

Comment: I think I'm getting it.  Last question: Is there *any* change in the code between the various `Store` classes? I don't see anything in there which actually uses `ContentType`. Or is the question simply about having near-duplicate code in the `Manager` and `Store` classes?

Comment: @Bobson Nope, it's purely just a storage bin as you can see. The ContentType on the higher level was strictly a way to get the right lock. There is no code changes - they all define the exact same operations and always will. They manage locks and nothing more. 

The question is basically just that - they're both storing nearly the exact same function(s). I wonder - is there no better to do this rather than wrapping a bunch of API calls?

Comment: Well, you should only have one `ContentLockStore` class, with one instance per `ContentType`, but the only alternative way to have the functions would be to provide a `ContentManagerStore.GetConnection(ContentType type)` function and use that to access the locking functions on the `ContentLockStore` directly.  I'm not sure if that counts as better.

Comment: @Bobson Not really - thanks for trying, though. Maybe the code duplication isn't so bad. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments and Your actual problem, it seems that You are unknowingly and partly using a [Proxy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternProxy.aspx).

So as a slight modification You should be having an interface extracted from ContentLockStore and then inherited in both of Your ContentLockManager and ContentLockStore classes, in Your case since the Manager class is having a third parameter as well, it is impossible to do even this, and **hence partly** implemented Proxy pattern.

I wonder whether Indexers can come to Your rescue, try reading [them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Besides Your main question, consider using [Constructor Injection](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection) in Your code, Your Manager class's constructor should not be having that loop, a factory should should be creating a dictionary and then passing it in the constructor. Doing that will promote testability.